# Prove that $f(x)<1+\pi/4$

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let $f:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function such that $$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}
$$
and $f(1)=1$  then prove that 
$$
f(x)<1+\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
for every $x \geqslant 1$.

My process:

I am not able to use the given differential equation as I don't know how to do it. If you can help me how to use the differential equation,I think then I can manage to solve this question.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: Integrate (treat $y$ as a constant) like https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F(x%5E2+%2B+4) ... then try MVT.

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 > 0$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$.